# Android: background colour + layer with transparent parts

Tags: android, graphics, background, drawable

So I have a background layer that I want available in multiple colours. Since it's black with coloured-markings, I thought it would suffice to make these markings transparent and place the layer on a correctly-coloured background.
Here's my try:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
layout.setBackgroundColor(colour);
int layerID = getResources().getIdentifier("bg_template", "drawable", getPackageName());
layout.setBackgroundResource(layerID);
```

So far, so good, except the transparent parts of the template don't stay transparent but become black instead.

Now, I cannot find a way to set the background of a drawable to null - like I did for image buttons, for example - so how would I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PNG images? JPEG images won't display transparent parts